# Problems hosting a Jetty application on the same server as IIS. 

Tags: iis, jetty, maven

I am a .Net programmer, lately developing a website in Jsp, using Jetty. I use Eclipse and the [Maven-Jetty plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin).

I have a virtual private server, which has IIS installed and is serving .NET websites. My domain name (for the Jsp website) redirects to this server.

My question is: How do I connect the domain name to the website in Jetty? Jetty listens to port 8080, and IIS to port 80.

I tried configuring a virtual host in a Jetty configuration file (jetty-web.xml) (followed [this manual](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Howto/Configure_Virtual_Hosts)), the result is: when I open a browser inside my server and navigate to mydomainname.com:8080 I get to the website. But if I do it externally, I get nothing.

1. What do I need to configure in order to get to my website?
2. How do I overcome the 8080 port number? or do I need to redirect my domain name to this port?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

1. It sounds like there is a firewall rule either on your server or upstream that is blocking port 8080. Call your host.
2. You can't easily. Only one service can bind to any single port. You could get another IP and add it to the server, then tell Jetty to listen on port 80 on that interface and then make an A record for that in your DNS zone, or you could possibly proxy it through IIS depending on what version of IIS. Getting an additional IP is probably the easiest way.

Comment: 1. I added an inbound rule in the firewall to allow HTTP traffic on port 8080, but it doesn't solve the problem. I still get nothing when I navigate to mydomainname:8080


2. I don't care if Jetty will continue to listen on port 8080, but I want my users to navigate to my domain name and get there, do I need a new IP for this?

Thank you

Comment: @Yaron thn something else is blocking that port. Call your host like I suggested. Also, your second question would require using IIS as proxy for Jetty. If you're unfamiliar with this type of setup, you will need to get another IP like I suggested. My answers to your follow ups were already in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have open the port to your router or create a rule to allow your router firewall to allow that port through.

Google 'What's my IP' and it will give your router IP address.  Then follow the instructions below.  If this allows you to access it outside the network on the WWW, then you should do two things:

1. Call your provider and get a static IP
2. Create rules allowing for access off network (public facing).

https://www.pcworld.com/article/244314/how_to_forward_ports_on_your_router.html